# How to install docker registry with helm on linod

Tags: docker, docker-registry, linode, helm3

I am following the documentation in [this page](https://www.linode.com/docs/guides/how-to-setup-a-private-docker-registry-with-lke-and-object-storage/#configure-your-docker-registry) and towards the bottom there is this code

```
helm install docker-registry stable/docker-registry -f docker-configs.yaml
```

When i run it, i get this error

```
WARNING: This chart is deprecated Error: unable to build kubernetes objects from release manifest: unable to recognize "": no matches for kind "Ingress" in version "extensions/v1beta1"
```

Is there an update to this command or is there something that am missing?

Answer (score 1):

[This is the source](https://git.app.uib.no/caleno/helm-charts/-/blob/84725d0e7921fb75860199fc8f52f2ee58e3d0a4/stable/docker-registry/templates/ingress.yaml) of the chart that gets installed. The apiVersion there is set to extensions/v1beta1 and that has been deprecated. Try using https://github.com/twuni/docker-registry.helm

helm repo add twuni https://helm.twun.io  && helm repo update
helm install twuni/docker-registry -f docker-configs.yaml

After that, I got this error: Getting this error: Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: Ingress.extensions "docker-registry" is invalid: annotations.kubernetes.io/ingress.class: Invalid value: "nginx": can not be set when the class field is also set

Removing kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx  from the docker-configs.yaml file helped me get rid of this error.